# postGIS SQL request with aggregating ST_Union()

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I have a postGIS table that looks like this :

```
id  |  value  | geometry(MultiPolygon)
1      10       ...
1      20       ...
1      30       ...
2      10       ...
2      20       ...
2      30       ...
```

What I wish to do is to create a new geometry column containing a Multipolygon which is the union of all the other polygons of rows having the same id and a smaller or equal 'value'.

So :

- first row 'new_geometry' would be identical to 'geometry'.
- Second row 'new_geometry' would be the union of the first and second row 'geometry'.
- Third row : union of rows 1,2,3
- equal to row 4
- etc

I have written something like this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.val, St_Union(t.geometry)
FROM 
    (SELECT cs.id, cs.value as val, cs.geometry
     FROM
         mytable cs 
         INNER JOIN 
             (SELECT DISTINCT value from myTable) v 
             ON (v.value <= cs.value)
     ) AS t
GROUP BY 
    t.val, t.id;
```

But the geometry column I get is not aggregated, it is equal to the original geometry column.
The aggregation work however if I 'GROUP BY' only by one criteria.

Comment: I assume lines 4, 5 6 have id 2, and "originid" is the same as "id".

Comment: You're right @Redoute, sorry about the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using ST_Union as accumulating window function:

```
SELECT
    id,
    value,
    ST_Union(geometry) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY value) AS geom
    FROM mytable;
```

Comment: That's working perfectly, thank you so much ! No I need to understand the magic behind this, I don't even see the condition on the value. I didn't know about window function, I will have a look. Thanks again.

Comment: hmm the fact that the partition ranges ~by default~ between the first and the current row ~only when~ a order by statement is added is tricky ! https://inovia.fr/window-functions-basics/ explains it very well.